# SharePoint caches incorrect credentials

Tags: sharepoint, credentials

Every morning when i fire up my VM and IE (in my host OS) and go to my SP site it always logs me on automatically as DOMAIN\george which is a user I created for testing permissions.

So every morning after that I click "sign in as a different user" to sign in as my sys admin user instead and most days that is the only user I use.  **Any idea why george's credentials are being cached?**

Part of "firing up my VM" is running a script that starts IIS as well as some services.  I'm not entirely sure SharePoint is responsible for this, could very well be ASP.Net.

EDIT: I've already tried clearing my cookies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had a very similar problem!  To solve it, go to 'User Accounts' under the Windows Control panel.

Navigate to 'Manage your network passwords'.  Select the domain you wish to clear and select 'Remove'.

You should now have a clean login dialogue box and when you check the 'remember me' box, this will be stored as the login default for that domain.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove the test login credentials using the User Account control panel applet in Windows 7

- Open the Manage Credentials link.
- Find the Sharepoint Login in the Windows Vault.
- Expand the address for the site
- Remove the test login for this site.

After doing this I am no longer prompted for the login and login as different user prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that you are using IE8, that caches my credentials as well it seems.

IE8 stores credentials for favourites it seems, don't ask me why. What you should do is log in as the needed user, then save a new favourite (or add it to the favourites bar by dragging it). Then use that link to go to your site.

Comment: IE8 stores credentials for favourites it seems, don't ask me why. What you should do is log in as the needed user, then save a new favourite.

Comment: In the "Delete Browsing History" dialog the first checkbox is "Preserve Favorites website data" which if unchecked when deleting cookies and Temporary Internet Files will also delete credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that there are no logins and passwords being stored by the browser? Assuming you are using IE, [see this article](http://www.inf.aber.ac.uk/advisory/faq/931/) on how to clear them.

Comment: Clearing my passwords had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If DOMAIN\george is same user ID you are logging in to the VM ? If that is the case try changing the Setting in IE that dictates what user name is send to the Server. Just go to **Tools - > Settings - > Security** and Click on Custom Level, scroll down to bottom and you will find User Authentication option Select the Prompt for User name and Password.

Comment: OK, great.  That works... kind of.  Now I get the prompt, but the default user is still dev\george.  So that basically saves me one click.  What I'd really like is the ability to change or clear out the saved "dev\george" credentials.

Comment: login box holds the dev\george because some point of time you should have say "Remember my Password" But thats not a Big Deal. Try saying Remember my Password in the Prompt for another user so that new user will also be saved in the list. If you want to clear all the items you can try clearing history.

Comment: checking "Remember my Password" has no affect.  I have already cleared my browser history.